# TeeChart is drawing lines from different axes in different speeds

Tags: android, teechart

I'm using TeeChart for drawing incoming data points that are received via BLE.
I created an TeeChart that has three costum axes to divide the Y-Axis in three equally sized parts. In addition, I initialized three FastLines and assigned each line to one custom axis.

```
//LINES
line1 = new Line(chart1.getChart());
line1.setColor(Color.black);
line1.getLinePen().setWidth(3);

line2 = new Line(chart1.getChart());
line2.setColor(Color.black);
line2.getLinePen().setWidth(3);

line3 = new Line(chart1.getChart());
line3.setColor(Color.black);
line3.getLinePen().setWidth(3);

//AXES
Axis axis0 = new Axis(false, false, chart1.getChart());
axis0.setVisible(true);
axis0.getLabels().setVisible(false);
axis0.getMinorTicks().setVisible(true);
axis0.getTicksInner().setVisible(false);
axis0.getTicks().setVisible(true);
chart1.getAxes().getCustom().add(axis0);
line1.setCustomVertAxis(axis0);
axis0.getTitle().getFont().setSize(textSizeY);
axis0.getTitle().getFont().setBold(true);
axis0.getTitle().setText("1 mV");
axis0.getTitle().setAngle(90);
axis0.setStartPosition(0);
axis0.setEndPosition(33);
axis0.setRelativePosition(0);
axis0.setAutomatic(false);
axis0.setIncrement(100);
axis0.setMinimum(-350);
axis0.setMaximum(+350);

Axis axis1 = new Axis(false, false, chart1.getChart());
axis1.setVisible(true);
axis1.getLabels().setVisible(false);
axis1.getMinorTicks().setVisible(true);
axis1.getTicksInner().setVisible(false);
axis1.getTicks().setVisible(true);
chart1.getAxes().getCustom().add(axis1);
line2.setCustomVertAxis(axis1);
axis1.getTitle().getFont().setSize(textSizeY);
axis1.getTitle().getFont().setBold(true);
axis1.getTitle().setText("1 mV");
axis1.getTitle().setAngle(90);
axis1.setStartPosition(33);
axis1.setEndPosition(66);
axis1.setRelativePosition(0);
axis1.setAutomatic(false);
axis1.setIncrement(100);
axis1.setMinimum(-350);
axis1.setMaximum(+350);

Axis axis2 = new Axis(false, false, chart1.getChart());
axis2.setVisible(true);
axis2.getLabels().setVisible(false);
axis2.getMinorTicks().setVisible(true);
axis2.getTicksInner().setVisible(false);
axis2.getTicks().setVisible(true);
chart1.getAxes().getCustom().add(axis2);
line3.setCustomVertAxis(axis2);
axis2.getTitle().getFont().setSize(textSizeY);
axis2.getTitle().getFont().setBold(true);
axis2.getTitle().setText("1 mV");
axis2.getTitle().setAngle(90);
axis2.setStartPosition(66);
axis2.setEndPosition(100);
axis2.setRelativePosition(0);
axis2.setAutomatic(false);
axis2.setIncrement(100);
axis2.setMinimum(-350);
axis2.setMaximum(+350);
```

As soon as there is data coming via BLE, the data points are plotted in the TeeChart as follows:

```
public static void addDataToTeeChart(short i){
    if(numberOfPlottablePoints >= 3*MAX_X_POINTS) {
        numberOfPlottablePoints = 0;
        line1.clear();
        line2.clear();
        line3.clear();
    }
    if (numberOfPlottablePoints < MAX_X_POINTS){
        line1.add(i);
    }
    else if (numberOfPlottablePoints < 2*MAX_X_POINTS){
        line2.add(i);
    }
    else if (numberOfPlottablePoints < 3*MAX_X_POINTS){
        line3.add(i);
    }
    numberOfPlottablePoints++;
}
```

The problem now is that while adding data to line1, everything is working just fine. But adding data to line2 becomes slower and the drawing gets some kind of juddery. And it's even worse for line3.

After clearing and back to adding points to line1, the plotting is fine again.

I was thinking that maybe there is too much data coming in. 
To rule that out, I added all incoming data to line1 (leaving line2 and line3 empty). That worked fine again!

I then tried to plot all data in line2 (leaving Line1 and Line3 empty) but there was no data plotted at all!

Also reducing MAX_X_POINTS to reduce the amout of plotted points, didn't do it for me.

For me it seems that the problem is with toggling between line1, line2 and line3 because when I just use one line (independet of which custom axis was used) the drawing is smooth!

I have no idea what else to try.

I hope that maybe someone can even tell me what exactly might be the problem or even has an suggestion what to do.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I did a rapid test with your code (with a few changes), and it seems to work fine for me here:

[image: screenshot]

The changes I did are basically:

- Disable manual configuration of the 3 custom axes scales.
- Set the chart to 2D.
- Fill the series with sample values instead of using your `addDataToTeeChart` function.

Find the code here:

```
        //LINES
        Line line1 = new Line(tChart1.getChart());
        line1.setColor(Color.black);
        line1.getLinePen().setWidth(3);

        Line line2 = new Line(tChart1.getChart());
        line2.setColor(Color.black);
        line2.getLinePen().setWidth(3);

        Line line3 = new Line(tChart1.getChart());
        line3.setColor(Color.black);
        line3.getLinePen().setWidth(3);

        //AXES
        Axis axis0 = new Axis(false, false, tChart1.getChart());
        axis0.setVisible(true);
        axis0.getLabels().setVisible(false);
        axis0.getMinorTicks().setVisible(true);
        axis0.getTicksInner().setVisible(false);
        axis0.getTicks().setVisible(true);
        tChart1.getAxes().getCustom().add(axis0);
        line1.setCustomVertAxis(axis0);
        //axis0.getTitle().getFont().setSize(textSizeY);
        axis0.getTitle().getFont().setBold(true);
        axis0.getTitle().setText("1 mV");
        axis0.getTitle().setAngle(90);
        axis0.setStartPosition(0);
        axis0.setEndPosition(33);
        axis0.setRelativePosition(0);
        /*axis0.setAutomatic(false);
        axis0.setIncrement(100);
        axis0.setMinimum(-350);
        axis0.setMaximum(+350);*/

        Axis axis1 = new Axis(false, false, tChart1.getChart());
        axis1.setVisible(true);
        axis1.getLabels().setVisible(false);
        axis1.getMinorTicks().setVisible(true);
        axis1.getTicksInner().setVisible(false);
        axis1.getTicks().setVisible(true);
        tChart1.getAxes().getCustom().add(axis1);
        line2.setCustomVertAxis(axis1);
        //axis1.getTitle().getFont().setSize(textSizeY);
        axis1.getTitle().getFont().setBold(true);
        axis1.getTitle().setText("1 mV");
        axis1.getTitle().setAngle(90);
        axis1.setStartPosition(33);
        axis1.setEndPosition(66);
        axis1.setRelativePosition(0);
        /*axis1.setAutomatic(false);
        axis1.setIncrement(100);
        axis1.setMinimum(-350);
        axis1.setMaximum(+350);*/

        Axis axis2 = new Axis(false, false, tChart1.getChart());
        axis2.setVisible(true);
        axis2.getLabels().setVisible(false);
        axis2.getMinorTicks().setVisible(true);
        axis2.getTicksInner().setVisible(false);
        axis2.getTicks().setVisible(true);
        tChart1.getAxes().getCustom().add(axis2);
        line3.setCustomVertAxis(axis2);
        //axis2.getTitle().getFont().setSize(textSizeY);
        axis2.getTitle().getFont().setBold(true);
        axis2.getTitle().setText("1 mV");
        axis2.getTitle().setAngle(90);
        axis2.setStartPosition(66);
        axis2.setEndPosition(100);
        axis2.setRelativePosition(0);
        /*axis2.setAutomatic(false);
        axis2.setIncrement(100);
        axis2.setMinimum(-350);
        axis2.setMaximum(+350);*/

        tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);
        line1.fillSampleValues(100);
        line2.fillSampleValues(100);
        line3.fillSampleValues(100);
```

To increment the fonts depending on the screen resolution I also use this:

```
private void proportionalFonts() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float myDensity = metrics.density;
    tChart1.getAspect().setFontZoom(tChart1.getAspect().getFontZoom()*myDensity*1.5);
}
```

If you still find problems with it, please try to arrange an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that didn't help me much. I do not have problems when I add values like you did. But when I add data point successively I still have the same problem. I recorded the screen while streaming and uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIv4uYxg6hwUVZfTjBrelJ5X1k/view); I'm not sure what you meant with sscce. What did I do wrong in my post? Not short enough or not complete? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: It would be desirable to get a complete and compilable project we can run to reproduce the problem here

Comment: Oh I see. I uploaded the project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIv4uYxg6hwVFhtRE5ybFlVcUk/view?usp=sharing). The code I posted in my question can be found in StarterFragment.java.

Comment: I see the project you attached includes `TeeChart.Android.jar` that requires a license to be used. Could you please remove it from that public .7z?

Comment: Also, that project looks as your complete project, it activates bluetooth, etc. Could you please reduce it to the minimum while it can still reproduce the exact problem you are reporting here with the chart?

Comment: I reduced the java files to a minimum. But I cannot remove the Bluetooth activation because the combination of receiving data via Bluetooth and displaying them in TeeChart is producing the issue. Uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIv4uYxg6hwaHBUTlRHS0p3RWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The first project you attached still gives public access to a restricted library.

Comment: The second project you attached still uses Bluetooth to acquire the data to be presented in the chart. I don't know what device should I connect to get that expected data. Anyway, if there is any problem with the charting component, it should be possible to isolate the problem and generate data manually for testing purposes.

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove the first file from bin.
I don't know how to isolate the problem and still reproduce it.

Comment: Other approach: Can you tell me anything about the limitations during real-time plotting? I mean something like a maximum sample frequency. After down-sampling the signal or clearing all three lines the drawing is much smoother.

Comment: There aren't limitations on the number of series or on the number of points. But, as you'll understand, the number of points to be drawn is one of the factors that affects the performance.